# Kendo Tabstrip appends URL on tabselect (MVC Razor View)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tabs, kendo-ui

I have a kendo tabstrip like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("EmployeeTabStrip")
    .Items(tabstrip =>
    {
        tabstrip.Add()
            .Text(Resources.Resources.ItemList)
            .Content(@<text>
                <div id="ListContainer" style=" height: 100%">
                    @Html.Partial("PartialEmployeeList")
                </div>
            </text>);
        tabstrip.Add()
           .Text(Resources.Resources.Edit)
           .Content(@<text>
                <div id="Container" style=" height: 100%">
                    @Html.Partial("PartialEmployeeForm")
                </div>
            </text>);
    })
    .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

But when I select a tab, it appends the tabstrip ID ("#*EmployeeTabStrip-1*") at the end of the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:36527/Setup/Employee?employeeId=33#EmployeeTabStrip-1
```

Does anyone know why this happens? If its Kendo's built-in, how can i override this?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the anchor tags that were rendered by Kendo (the tabs are rendered as anchor tags) had an `href` attribute with that value, i.e.

```
<a class="k-link" href="#EmployeeTabStrip-1">Tab 1</a>
```

If you look at the generated HTML source I imagine you'd see something similar to that. As far as I know this is not something that Kendo does, I've not seen it on my TabStrips and it doesn't occur on the online web demo [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/index.html) which demonstrates a similar control initialization to your sample.

It may be a version issue (try updating to the latest Kendo release) or there may be some other factor at play.

Comment: Yes your're right! The anchor tag has ID property in it so its natural that it'll append to the URL when clicked. But I didnt add it though. Might be a Kendo bug. Im using Kendo Q3(2012.3.1315). Its the latest non-Beta version and still Im getting this bug. By the way, Im using MVC Razor View.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest internal build or the beta version of Kendo UI Extensions. This should be already fixed.

Comment: Im currently using  Kendo Q3(2012.3.1315).This is the latest version available for free users.